# Why is every $l^p(\mathbb{K})$ a dual of some normed space?

Tags: dual-spaces

Why is every $l^p(\mathbb{K})$ a dual of some normed space?

The $l^p(\mathbb{K})$ space is the space:

$$\{ w \in F(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{K}) : \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |w(n)|^p < \infty\}$$

where $F(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{K})$ is the space of functions $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$.

Is it simply because the duals of normed spaces are continuous functions (or bounded linear) and functions of $l^p$ are a type of continuous functions? But how do I know that $w$s are continuous?

Comment: Is $\Bbb K$ supposed to be $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes of course.